# My JavaScript is only working in a fiddle or Codepen

Tags: javascript, html, function, codepen

im trying a function in my HTML file, it should be working. I tried it in Codepen but when i try to add it with , it doesn't work
Also, i have very small knowledge with JavaScript so maybe my mistake is really dumb.
I also tried adding

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Above my script but this didn't change anything, maybe i picked the wrong library ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<!-- The team bars -->
<div class=teams-main-container>
    <a href="C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop\Website\N1\team-page.html"</a><div class=team-bar-1>
    <img src='C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop\Website\Images\EUROPE.png' width="35px" height="20px" class=E_U>
    <h1 id=team-name>Les papillons verts</h1>
    <h1 id=number-of-players>0/3</h1>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Here is the CSS :

```
 body {
    display:grid; 
    font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background: #2a2d38;
}

.body_class_for_apex_game_page {
    grid-template-rows:  50px 0.5fr 2fr ;
    grid-template-columns:  0.5fr 2fr 0.5fr;
  }

/* First team prototype */

.team-bar-1{
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor:pointer;
    height: min(15vw, 100px);
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top:10px;
    background-color: #2a2d38;
    transition: 0.1s ease-in-out all;
    border:solid #444444 2px;
}

.team-bar-1:hover{
    border-color: #6e6e6e;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.E_U {
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    width:min(4vw, 35px);
    height:min(3vw, 20px);
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left:1%;
}

#team-name{
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    margin-left:1%;
    color:white;
    font-size: min(5vw, 35px);
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#number-of-players{
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    color:white;
    font-size: min(5vw, 35px);
    align-self: flex-end;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 1%;
}
```

and my function :

```
function multiplyNode(node, count, deep) {
    for (var i = 0, copy; i < count - 1; i++) {
        copy = node.cloneNode(deep);
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(copy, node);
    }
}

multiplyNode(document.querySelector('.team-bar-1'), 15, true);
```

Comment: What file is the js code saved in?
Perhaps try including that into your markup?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you forgot to include js file to your html.
Use some `<script src="...">` magic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).